# Existence of different Jordan-Holder filtrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, derived-categories

Assume $X/\mathbb{C}$ is a  projective K3 surface. Let $\sigma$ be a (geometric) Bridgeland stability condition for $\rm{D}^b(X)$.

My questions are :

1. Is there any nontrivial example of $E \in \rm{D}^b(X)$ which is $\sigma$-semistable and admits different Jordan-Holder filtrations?
   i.e. the order that the JH factors arise is different.
   (Here the nontrivialness means $E$ is not a direct sum of $\sigma$-stable objects of the same phase)
2. If such $E$ exists, is there any criterion for which JH factors can appear as the subobject or quotient of $E$ in the corresponding tilting heart of $\sigma$ ?

Thanks for any answers or comments!